# javascript get keyboard keydown and keyup input

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I want to send server when client does keydown or keyup.

However, sometimes It doesn't work well. It misses some event and "keyboard array" doesn't [] when I leave my hands to keyboard.

I maked "keyboard array" to find duplicate input, and when window is not focused I initialized it. Here's my code.

```
var keyarr = [];
window.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(keyarr.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1) {
            //delete keyCode
        keyarr.splice(keyarr.indexOf(e.keyCode),1);
            //websocket.send(keycode);
    }
}
window.onkeydown = function(e){
      //check keyCode available
      if(!e.repeat && keyarr.indexOf(e.keyCode) == -1) {
            //add keyCode
            keyarr.push(e.keyCode);
            //websocket.send(keycode);
      }
}
window.onblur = function(){
      keyarr = [];
      //websocket.send(keycode);
}
```

Why some keydown and keyup event doesn't delivered well?

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes It doesn't work well :- On particular key press?

Comment: Before continuing, [good to know about keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

Comment: What is the `dict` array?

Comment: Sorry for asking with low readability :). It means keyarr does not match to pressed key of keyboard. Thanks for your notice

Comment: and dict array is keyboard shortcuts that I want to input. actually it does not need. Sorry.

Comment: Give your array of keyboard codes, in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To answer your question:

It can be due to WI-FI connections or computer performance. But I'll try to help you optimize your code a bit to make it work better

## Let's get couple thing out of the way:

- WTH is your **dict** variable and what does it represent. Please be more explicit
- The sections:

  > dict[e.keyCode] != undefined

  Can be replaced with:

  > dict[e.keyCode]
- In this section:

  > if(dict[e.keyCode] != undefined && keyarr.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1) {
  >     //delete keyCode
  >     keyarr.splice(keyarr.indexOf(e.keyCode),1);
  >   }

  You're looking up the index of the keycode in the array TWICE. Store **keyarr.indexOf(e.keyCode)** in a local variable

Comment: I found one case is cause by right mouse click. and I think computer performance error can cause things to. Sorry for asking with low readability and this answer helped me a lot.

Comment: No problem :D It's my first time on Stackoverflow too